# Why is my UI unresponsive?

Tags: c#, wpf

My login window is highly unresponsive. I'm not really sure why is this. I'm using MVVM light as my MVVM framework. I handle the login button click through a `RelayCommand`, the command handler (I know it's bad practice to pass the whole `PasswordBox` as a parameter, it's breaking the MVVM pattern, but please focus on the question). The command handler is the following:

```
LoginButtonClicked = new GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand<System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox>((pwdBox) =>
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pwdBox.Password))
    {
        MessageBoxRequested("Neuspešno logovanje", "Molimo unesite i korsničko ime i lozinku");
        return;
    }

    ProgressDialogRequested();

    bool validated = false;

    try
    {
        validated = TotalSport.Framework.UserManagement.EmployeeStore.ValidateEmployee(this.Username, pwdBox.Password);
    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Core.ObjectNotFoundException)
    {
        MessageBoxRequested("Logovanje neuspešno", "Zaposleni sa tim imenom ne postoji!");
        pwdBox.Password = string.Empty;
        return;
    }

    pwdBox.Password = string.Empty;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(validated);

    if (validated)
    {
        Client.Views.MainWindow mw = new Client.Views.MainWindow(this.Username);
        mw.Show();
        CloseRequested();
    }
    else
        MessageBoxRequested("Logovanje neuspešno", "Pogrešna lozinka!");
});
```

`ValidateEmployee` hashed the supplied string and compares it to a value stored in the DB. I think it's the cause of my problems (it most likely is, since it's a slow hash - PBDKF2 - and a DB query in a single method), but I'm not sure why. It has nothing to do with the UI thread and the LoginWindow itself.

The relevant event handlers on the actual window:

```
((ViewModels.LoginViewModel)this.DataContext).MessageBoxRequested += (title, message) =>
{
    this.ShowMessageAsync(title, message);
};
((ViewModels.LoginViewModel)this.DataContext).ProgressDialogRequested += () =>
{
    this.ShowProgressAsync("Test", "test");
};
((ViewModels.LoginViewModel)this.DataContext).CloseRequested += () =>
{
    this.Close();
};
```

Any input on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your LoginButtonClicked handler, use the following code:

```
var username = this.Username;

var password = pwdBox.Password;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => //This will run using a Thread-Pool thread which will not cause the UI to be unresponsive.
{
    //Do expensive operations here, like data access
    //You cannot access the UI here

    bool valid = DoSomeExpensiveCallsToDetermineIfPasswordIsValid(username, password);

    return valid;
})
.ContinueWith( t => //This will run on the UI thread
{

    bool valid = t.Result;

    if (valid)
    {
        //Do some UI to indicate that the password is valid
    }
    else
    {
        //Do some UI to indicate that the password is not valid
    }


}, CancellationToken.None,
TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, //Only run this if the first action did not throw an exception
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); //Use the UI thread to run this action
```

This code assumes that DoSomeExpensiveCallsToDetermineIfPasswordIsValid does not throw exceptions. Handle any exceptions inside such method.

This code runs the first action using a background thread, and then the second action in the UI thread.

The code that runs in the UI thread should be quick.

Comment: Works like a charm! So to clarify some things I'm not sure about: 1. So the ViewModel **DOES** run on the UI thread? I thought it doesn't :( 2. Even if I make a method `async`, it still runs on the same thread? 3. Is this comparable to running a `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: 1) Yes, WPF ViewModels are invoked using the UI thread. 2) marking a method async does not mean it will run on a different thread, use Task.Factory.StartNew to run actions on a worker thread. 3) Yes it is comparable to BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Yeah, I totally didn't think about what ViewModels actually are. Obviously you couldn't bind anything if they were on a separate thread.

About 3). What are the differences?

Comment: One of the main differences is that using the Task Parallel Library (TPL) (e.g. Tasks) is more flexible, you can use it to create a chain of continuations of tasks. It supports cancellation (i.e., allowing for canceling the task before it is done). TPL is a big component in .NET, it has a lot of features, I just mentioned a few. BackgroundWorker has a very specific use.